# What is a word that means I enjoy human and/or animal interaction?

Tags: single-word-requests

I don't know if there is a word for the above question or not, but if there is please help.

I enjoy human or animal interaction, and without such I begin to feel extremely bored and lose interest in most everything, even stuff that would normally help a person be free of that boredom.

If nobody is around, I feel bored and usually stop the game I'm playing, or book I'm reading, begin talking a bit less, and just don't feel up to doing really anything. However if there is someone around, or if there is an animal around like a cat or dog, I lose that bored feeling and begin talking more and doing the above things stated previously.

What is the word I'm looking for? I honestly do not know.

If someone could get back to me quickly, that would be much appreciated.

Comment: If nobody is around, who were you talking to in order to be able to talk less?

Comment: Sounds like you are ***gregarious*** by nature

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Sociable](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sociable) works really well here (specifically, definition 2a on that site).

> 1 : inclined by nature to companionship with others of the same species : SOCIAL
>
> 2 a : inclined to seek or enjoy companionship
>
> 2 b : marked by or conducive to friendliness or pleasant social relations

Also from Merriam-Webster, this examples shows the use of "sociable" when dealing with animals:

> "The gorillas that are interacting with the kids might be more chill and sociable generally, and that might be what’s attractive about them."

Comment: Hi Anubhav, welcome to EL&U. This is halfway to being a good answer, but note that an answer on this site is expected to be *authoritative, detailed, and explain why it is correct*. You can [edit] your answer to add a published definition (linked to the source), and perhaps a sample sentence, for each of the words you've proposed. For further guidance, see [answer] and take the **[Tour]** :-)

Comment: Hi, I've modified the answer. Please let me know if it's better now.

Comment: Yes Anubhav, nicely done. +1 :-)

Answer (score 0):

You may also consider the word ***[extroverted](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/extroversion)***:

> the act, state, or habit of being predominantly concerned with and obtaining gratification from what is outside the self
>   <sub>*definition from [m-w.com](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/extroversion)*</sub>